# How do I allow https on localhost?

Tags: windows, postgresql, https, localhost, postgrest

I want to test an app API but I need to have a domain with a secure HTTP protocol for to redirect to. Currently, I don't have a domain but I've thought about the possibility of HTTPS on localhost, is that possible?

PS: OS is Windows & I'm using [postgREST](http://postgrest.com/) to run on localhost.

Comment: You have to install an OpesSSL certificate. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04 Do as this for Ubuntu

Comment: Do you have a way to do it for Windows?

Comment: Are you using wamp or XAMPP?

Comment: @Imesha I'm using postgREST. You can check it out, so far I cannot find any docs about https, still currently searching.